# Swift UIView.animateWithDuration disappears while loading content

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uianimation

I use a simple animation that slides down a small view (this view contains some labels an imageView).
The animation works but when I try to set the content of the the labels and the imageView, the view disappears.

Any help?

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0,
                usingSpringWithDamping: springDamping,
                initialSpringVelocity: velocity, options: option!, animations: {
                    self.sliderUserInfo.frame.origin = self.sliderUserInfoPosition
                }, completion: {finished  in
                    if finished {
                        self.loadContentView()
                    }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as:

```
    var newFrame = self.sliderUserInfo.frame
    newFrame.origin = self.sliderUserInfoPosition
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0,
        usingSpringWithDamping: springDamping,
        initialSpringVelocity: velocity, options: option!, animations: {
            self.sliderUserInfo.frame = newFrame
        }, completion: {finished  in
            if finished {
                self.loadContentView()
            }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Autolayout is putting the view back where it belongs.  In your animation, instead of changing the frame origin, change the constraint constant of the constraint between the view and the top of the superview.

Either create one:

```
var cHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

// Start the bottom of the view off the screen
cHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(item: sliderUserInfo, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: -1.0)
```

Or reference it from the storyboard:

```
@IBOutlet var cHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Then animate the change:

```
// Animate the change of the constraint
self.cHeight.constant = self.sliderUserInfo.frame.height
// Note we animate the layoutIfneeded
UIView.animateWithDuration(1, delay: 0,
            usingSpringWithDamping: springDamping,
            initialSpringVelocity: velocity, options: option!, animations: {
                self.sliderUserInfo.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: {finished  in
                if finished {
                    self.loadContentView()
                }
        })
```